# Null value when checking which submit button has been pressed

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have been trying for a good two hours now and am still not getting results. I have some html like so inside a "test.jsp" file

`<input type ="submit" name="watch" value="Edit" id="edit"></input>`

`<input type ="submit" name="case" value="Edit" id="editt"></input>`

Then I have a form which when pressing either of the buttons above pops up using jquery

```
<form action="servlet.jsp" method="post">
<fieldset>
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br>
  <label for="Price">Price</label>
  <input type="text" name="Price" id="price" value=""><br>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And my JSP consists of

```
<% String param = request.getParameter("watch"); %>
<% String param2 = request.getParameter("case"); %>
```

So basically I have two edit buttons, dependent on which edit button is pressed it should pre populate the form values. For now I have the form values as "" because my `getParameter` is always coming up as null regardless of what button I press.

I have tried the following code in terms of checking whether the value is NULL to then do something if they are not etc but both return null regardless of  the button

```
if(param !=null){
    //assign variables and populate with data x
}
//and so on
```

So my question is, firstly, am I "getting" the parameter correctly. And secondly, if so, any ideas why I am getting both of those parameters as null regardless of which submit button I press.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, input is a self closing tag. That means you close it with a space followed by `/>` not with `</input>`:

```
<input type="submit" name="watch" value="Edit" id="edit" />
<input type="submit" name="case"  value="Edit" id="editt" />
```

That's probably the issue.  Your code may very well work after that change.  But I would note it would be easier to name both buttons the same thing and give them different values, because you only have to read one and switch on the value:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Edit X" id="edit" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Edit Y" id="editt" />
```

Then in the servlet or other JSP:

```
String button = request.getParameter("submit");
if(button == null)
{
  out.print("no form was submitted");
  return;
}
else if("Edit X".equals(button))
{
  out.print("button 1 was pressed");
  return;
}
else if("Edit Y".equals(button))
{
  out.print("button 2 was pressed");
  return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for your help, however I tried this and it just keeps passing it as null...

Comment: You're using Ajax, aren't you? You should specify that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your JSP should be:

```
<% String param = request.getParameter("edit"); %>
<% String param2 = request.getParameter("editt"); %>
```

Comment: Its the names that are sent, not the ids, so no.

Comment: The id only matters to Javascript, i.e. to client code.